# Is there any Email alerting feature for Elasticsearch?

Tags: email, elasticsearch, alert, kibana, packetbeat

I'm using Packetbeat, Elasticsearch 1.5 and kibana 4. I want an email alerting feature for elasticsearch. Is there any tool or open source tool for this email feature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We don't know much about your use case, but [Elasticsearch Watcher](https://www.elastic.co/products/watcher) or [ElastAlert](http://elastalert.readthedocs.org/en/latest/elastalert.html) might be two options you want to check out.

Comment: There's also another way to implement very simple alerts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39681300/how-to-set-up-percolator-to-return-when-an-aggregation-value-hits-a-certain-thre/39761323#39761323

Answer (score 3):

Elasticsearch Watcher is the best option but it is paid. You can always validate it using the trial period. Here is an article on how to use Watcher for Email alerting

[Real Time Alerting using ElasticSearch Watcher](http://hadooptutorials.co.in/tutorials/elasticsearch/real-time-alerting-using-elasticsearch-watcher.html)

Comment: That was already proposed in Val's answer. What is the news that you add in your answer?

Comment: My answer contains link to article on how to implement it.