# How to set up percolator to return when an aggregation value hits a certain threshold?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-percolate

Take the following aggregation query as an example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "groupBy": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "CustomerName"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "points_sum": {
          "stats": {
            "field": "TransactionAmount"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

I am interested in knowing when any CustomerName has an average TransactionAmount (stats.avg) that is above some threshold for all of that customer's purchases, as soon as I index a document that would put my average above that threshold. It seems like percolator is designed for matching documents to rules, more or less, but I can't find any good examples of using percolator to match rules that are based on aggregation results.

Is this possible? Is percolator the best solution here? Is there another/better solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: you could achieve this using [watcher](https://www.elastic.co/videos/watcher-lab-using-elasticsearch-aggregations-in-your-watch)   but  requires  [subscription](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/current/license-management.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Watcher](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/current/index.html) commercial product for that and define the following watch:

```
PUT _watcher/watch/transaction_alert
{
  "trigger": {
    "schedule": {
      "interval": "1m"
    }
  },
  "input": {
    "search": {
      "request": {
        "indices": "transactions",
        "types": "transaction",
        "body": {
          "query": {
            "match_all": {}
          },
          "size": 0,
          "aggs": {
            "groupBy": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "CustomerName"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "points_sum": {
                  "stats": {
                    "field": "TransactionAmount"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "condition": {
    "script": {
      "inline": "return ctx.payload.aggregations.groupBy.buckets.findAll{ cust -> cust.points_sum.avg >= 200}"
    }
  },
  "actions": {
    "send_email": { 
      "email": {
        "to": "<username>@<domainname>", 
        "subject": "Customer Notification - Transaction > 200",
        "body": "The attached customers have a transaction average above $200"
        "attachments" : {
           "data.yml" : {
              "data" : {
                 "format" : "yaml" 
              }
           }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

To sum up:

- Watcher is a commercial product
- ElastAlert doesn't support it (yet) and [requires some effort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39754790/how-to-have-elastalert-triger-when-the-sum-of-a-field-for-all-documents-that-ma) to make it work

There's another much simpler and cheaper way to achieve this using Logstash. Even though the [`elasticsearch`](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-elasticsearch) input plugin doesn't support aggregations, it is possible to use the [`http_poller`](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-http_poller) input plugin in order to send an aggregation query to Elasticsearch at regular intervals. Then using a filter you can check if the desired threshold is attained or not, and finally, alert someone by email if that's the case using the [`email`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-email.html) output plugin.

The configuration basically goes like this (note that your above aggregation query needs to be URL-encoded and sent to ES using the [`source=...` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_request_body_in_query_string)). Also note that I've modified your query to sort the buckets according to `points_sum.avg` (desc)

```
input {
  http_poller {
    urls => {
      test1 => 'http://localhost:9200/your-index/_search?source=%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%22match_all%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C%22aggs%22%3A%7B%22groupBy%22%3A%7B%22terms%22%3A%7B%22field%22%3A%22CustomerName%22%2C%22order%22%3A%7B%22points_sum.avg%22%3A%22desc%22%7D%7D%2C%22aggs%22%3A%7B%22points_sum%22%3A%7B%22stats%22%3A%7B%22field%22%3A%22TransactionAmount%22%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D%2C%22size%22%3A0%7D'
   }
   # checking every 10 seconds
   interval => 10
   codec => "json"
  }
}
filter {
  split {
    field => "[aggregations][groupBy][buckets]" 
  }
}
output {
  if [aggregations][groupBy][buckets][points_sum][avg] > 200 {
    email {
      to => "<username>@<domainname>"
      subject => "Customer Notification - Transaction > 200",
      body => "The customer %{[aggregations][groupBy][buckets][key]} has a transaction average above $200"
    }
  }
}
```

Agreed, this is a very simplistic implementation, but it should be working and you can build upon it to make it smarter, with Logstash and your imagination the limit is the sky ;-)

**UPDATE 2**

Another node.js tool call [elasticwatch](https://github.com/QXIP/elasticwatch-js) could also be leveraged to do this.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I wonder if the only solution to this really is to buy a 30k yearly license?

Comment: There are also free alternatives, such as [ElastAlert](https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert) by the Yelp folks.

Comment: I see you've been [trying ElastAlert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39754790/how-to-have-elastalert-triger-when-the-sum-of-a-field-for-all-documents-that-ma) :-)

Comment: I've added yet another alternative.

Comment: Hahah, I've been playing with any options I can get my hands on.  Hadn't considered the logstash option... Hopefully I can pull something together, thanks for all your help :)

Comment: No luck yet, but I hadn't realized that I forgot to award the bounty.  All yours!