# How to have elastalert triger when the sum of a field, for all documents that match a query, exceeds some value

Tags: elasticsearch, elastalert

Can elastalert be triggered when the sum of a field for all documents that match a query exceeds some value? Say each document has a "price" value - Can elastalert be triggered when the sum of the "price" values over the last day exceeds 200, for example?

Example document:

```
{
  type: "transaction",
  price: 20.32
}
```

Example rule in english:

`The sum of all documents where type = 'transaction' over the past hour exceeds 200`

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported out of the box by ElastAlert.

There's [an open issue](https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert/issues/401) which is still unresolved yet, as well as a related [pull request](https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert/pull/657) which hasn't been merged yet.

However, you may be able to modify ElastAlert by yourself by following the steps described in the issue and using the [contributed patch](https://github.com/errordaiwa/elastalert/commit/9b33c378b468c4c1d38fcc94e0ffe18941fe096b). Should be a no brainer.

Comment: If you don't feel like modifying ElastAlert, see my updated answer in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39761323/4604579), which provides yet another a free alternative ;-)

Comment: @Jim do you still need any more info on this?